# Visual GDB pthread undefined reference to

Tags: visual-studio, linker, include

again i'm having trouble with Visual GDB in VisualStudio.

I include  but when i call pthread_create(...) i get the following error:

```
undefined reference to 'pthread_create'
```

Is this because the linker does not include the pthread files? Is there a way to tell VisualStudio what to include?

Comment: include <pthread.h>

Comment: It is not realy a duplicate - the question is about visual GDB. For others: In VisualGDB properties you can add linker arguments, than it works well